# Control + D not working in mail

Tags: 14.04, ssh, putty

I am trying to test the mail capabilities of my server. I simply do this `mail -s "This is a test" myemail@domain.com`, then it prompts me for `Cc:` then the body. After typing into the body I am hitting Control + D, however it seems that it is not exiting in the body. What am I missing here?

Comment: The problem may lie in the misconfiguration of `mail`. To detect that, run it in a debug mode: `$mail -s "test" me@example.com --debug-level=3` In my case it hanged during sending body. You can find more information in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/753062/251416).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Control+D:

1. `mail -s "This is a test" myemail@domain.com` - hit ENTER
2. Write eMail body text, when you're done, press ENTER.
3. Enter a single dot on the new line, press ENTER again to complete the body.
4. You're now asked to provide Cc: addresses, just skip this with ENTER

Voila, you're done.